# Java - mixed data types / printing them

Tags: java, arraylist

lets say I have my owndefined datatype like this:

```
    public class InformationType
    {
        private String brand;
        private int number;
        private double power;

        public PurchaseInfo(String brand, int number, double power)
        {
             this.brand = brand;
             this.number = number;
             this.power = power;
        }
        public String getBrand()
        {
            return this.brand;
        }
        public int getNumber()
        {
            return this.number;
        }
        public double getPower()
        {
            return this.power;
        }
    }
```

then i have a program which prints strings that is either just a string, an int or a double, and i add them all to an array with the same type as my created one:

```
      theInfo.add(new InformationType(theBrand, theNumber, thePower))
```

when I do a loop to just check if i got em right i just get pointers (i think its called) to them and not the real string/int/double. i want to print all my types, without using my getters. this is what i do:

```
     for (InformationType x : theInfo)
     {
          System.out.println(x);
     }
```

and i get stuff like InformationType@abcd12412413 etc..

and yeah, i made theInfo with:

```
     ArrayList<InformationType> theInfo = new ArrayList<>();
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override `toString`.  e.g.:

```
public class InformationType {
    ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + brand + "," + number + "," + power + "}";
    }
}
```

This will now automatically get called by `println`.

Comment: working now. I actually did that buy I had "return String" and then had "return String.format", so i removed the String-part and edited yours. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should override [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) in `InformationType`.

The overriden method should relfect how you want your instance of `InformationType` to be represented as a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `toString()` method in your `InformationType` class. Write it so that it returns a String of the data in the format you want. Perhaps something like this:

```
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s %d %f", brand, number, power);
}
```

All objects have a `toString()` method, but the default implementation is to print the type name, the "@" sign, and the hash code of the object in hex. When you override `toString()`, you get to return whatever you like. The only restriction is that you shouldn't really return `null`.